# C# AppendDataBoundItems="True" property allow duplicate in ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Listbox inside detailsview with myown selectedvalue property.

When I set `Appenddatabounditems="true"` then the values of Listbox is get duplicated otherwise, when I set `"AppendDatabounditems="false"` then the Listbox selectedvalue is not working.

Kindly advice me, how to avoid duplication in Listbox.

My code snippet are as follows.

[ASPX page]

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvProfile" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="odsProfileData">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Full Name" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Products">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <iac:MyMultiSelectionDropDown ID="ListBox1" OnDataBound="Databound" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="odsProducts" DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                        SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedValuesCSV='<%# Bind("Products") %>'>
                    </iac:MyMultiSelectionDropDown>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <iac:MyMultiSelectionDropDown ID="ListBox1" OnDataBound="Databound" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="odsProducts" DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                        SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedValuesCSV='<%# Bind("Products") %>'>
                    </iac:MyMultiSelectionDropDown>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="button" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit User Profile" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>


<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsProfileData" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetProfileData"
        TypeName="MultiSelectionTest.App_Code.TestData" />
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsProducts" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetProducts"
        TypeName="MultiSelectionTest.App_Code.TestData" />
```

[TestData.CS]

```
//Using this class file i filled the ListBox.

 public class TestData
    {
        public List<ProfileData> GetProfileData()
        {
            List<ProfileData> ret = new List<ProfileData>();
            ret.Add(new ProfileData("Test1", "1,2"));
            return ret;
        }
        public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {

            List<Product> ret = new List<Product>();
            ret.Add(new Product(1, "Product1"));
            ret.Add(new Product(2, "Product2"));
            ret.Add(new Product(3, "Product3"));
            ret.Add(new Product(4, "Product4"));
            return ret;
        }

        public class ProfileData
        {
            public ProfileData(string fullName, string products)
            {
                FullName = fullName;
                Products = products;
            }
            public string FullName { get; set; }
            public string Products { get; set; }
        }
        public class Product
        {
            public Product(int id, string fullName)
            {
                ID = id;
                FullName = fullName;
            }
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string FullName { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

[MyMultiselectionDropDown.cs]

```
 public string SelectedValuesCSV
        {
            get
            {
                string ret = string.Empty;
                foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem li in this.Items)
                {
                    if (li.Selected)
                    {
                        ret += "," + li.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
                return ret.TrimStart(',');
            }
            set
            {
                if (!_noUpdate)
                {
                    _noUpdate = true;
                    this.DataBind();

                }
                _noUpdate = false;

                IdContainer values = new IdContainer(value);
                foreach (string val in values)
                {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem li = this.Items.FindByValue(val);
                    if (li != null)
                        li.Selected = true;
                }
                //MultiSelectionTest.App_Code.TestData nn = new TestData();
                //object bb = nn.GetProfileData();
            }
        }
```

Using this class file I get the SelectedValues.

Kindly advice me.

Answer (score 0):

AppenddataboundItems = "true" means 
that u want to add all the products or (the data coming from database)+ "select" 
in the listbox